# How to check whether Selenium Server is running

Tags: php, windows, selenium, phpunit

I have bunch of phpunit tests, part of them using selenium, and i need to know wheteher selenium server is running or not (windows). Is there way to check it from php?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, Selenium server accepts commands on localhost port 4444.

So you could do this:

```
<?php
$selenium_running = false;

$fp = @fsockopen('localhost', 4444);
if ($fp !== false) {
    $selenium_running = true;
    fclose($fp);
}

var_dump($selenium_running);
```

I don't personally like using `@`, but `fsockopen` insists on throwing a PHP notice, when the connection fails. Having this warning in output or even in log file is just annoying.

Comment: Using `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost` may result in faster response since avoids DNS roundups (I measured cca 2.2-2.7 secs dropped to 0.2-0.4 sec).