# How to check if selenium server is running in background

Tags: selenium

Hi am using selenium 2.0 with netbeans IDE.
I am writing a code to check if selenium server is running.But am not able to identify if its running or not because there no process in task manager or its not listed in services. Am using java code. So can anyone check with it and do the needfull.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily check the selenium server is running or not. 
open this link in broweser - http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status

It will show the log of running server otherwise show unable to connect/page is not availble.

Or You can also check with http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=getLogMessages
If serveris runnning then it will show 'ok' in browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can see, if the port is active, see also

[How to check whether Selenium Server is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657803/how-to-check-whether-selenium-server-is-running)